# php - write to a file to a specific div tag using file_put_contents

Tags: php

I currently render some HTML on one of my pages by called another file with that HTML. I use `file_get_contents` and call that file with the HTML and render it. I have noticed that even if I call that file with just HTML it slows down my site by 3/4 of a second.

I have discovered if I could just have that HTML in the page its much faster. I have to do it this way for your information

So my question is how can I use `file_put_contents` and have it place some HTML in a specific `div` tag.

**For Instance**

```
<div id="thisdiv"></div>
```

To clarify I do not want to call an external file and render the HTML when the file is called. I want the HTML to be part of the file. So I want a cron job to insert the text into the div sometime in the middle of the night.

My goal is to have a cron job write to the file once a day so that its already part of the file. I dont need it to load every time the page loads and this specific page gets 500,000 pageviews a day

With 500,000 pageviews I cant call a file that many times. I need it to be part of the file.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Javascript to me... Using AJAX will eliminate your original page load delay, and it's very easy to target the element to insert retrieved data into.

Comment: does Javascript reduce load times?

Comment: It decreases **server** load time, because it's processed on the client's end, meaning your request will be performed once the page is already loaded (you display a spinner while it loads or something).

Comment: My goal is to have a cron job write to the file once a day so that its already part of the file. I dont need it to load every time the page loads and this specific page gets 500,000 pageviews a day

Comment: Useful info, put that in your question. You'll probably need to use DOMDocument or similar to insert HTML code into a specific element like that (with PHP)

Answer (score 1):

Here random.php is put into index.php. I think this is what you want...

**randomfile.php**

```
<p>This is just a random file with some content in a p tag </p>
```

**index.php** - the main file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HomePage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <?php include('randomfile.php'); ?>       
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Output will be

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HomePage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>This is just a random file with some content in a p tag </p>      
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```